# "cannot infer an appropriate lifetime" when attempting to return a chunked response with hyper

Tags: rust, stream, lifetime, chunked, hyper

I would like to return binary data in chunks of specific size. Here is a [minimal example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7ea6567d63ef02c00900a2279cd61a0b).

I made a wrapper struct for `hyper::Response` to hold my data like status, status text, headers and the resource to return:

```rust
pub struct Response<'a> {
    pub resource: Option<&'a Resource>
}
```

This struct has a `build` method that creates the `hyper::Response`:

```rust
impl<'a> Response<'a> {
    pub fn build(&mut self) -> Result<hyper::Response<hyper::Body>, hyper::http::Error> {
        let mut response = hyper::Response::builder();
        match self.resource {
            Some(r) => {
                let chunks = r.data
                .chunks(100)
                .map(Result::<_, std::convert::Infallible>::Ok);
                response.body(hyper::Body::wrap_stream(stream::iter(chunks)))       
            },
            None => response.body(hyper::Body::from("")),
        }
    }    
}
```

There is also another struct holding the database content:

```rust
pub struct Resource {
    pub data: Vec<u8>
}
```

Everything works until I try to create a chunked response. The Rust compiler gives me the following error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:14:15
   |
14 |         match self.resource {
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 11:6...
  --> src/main.rs:11:6
   |
11 | impl<'a> Response<'a> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/main.rs:14:15
   |
14 |         match self.resource {
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `Option<&Resource>`
              found `Option<&'a Resource>`
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/main.rs:19:31
   |
19 |                 response.body(hyper::Body::wrap_stream(stream::iter(chunks)))       
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `From<&[u8]>`
              found `From<&'static [u8]>`
```

I don't know how to fulfill these lifetime requirements. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: The error shows that `Resource` is `http::resource::Resource` but I don't see that type in the `http` crate docs. Can you show where it comes from?

Comment: This is also a struct I created as an abstraction to the database row.

Comment: @rodrigo Building the body just from Resource::data is working. But as resource data can get quiet large, I'd like to return Chunked Response instead and I cannot figure out how to do it correctly using hyper framework.

Comment: @Shepmaster. Here is the minimal example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7ea6567d63ef02c00900a2279cd61a0b

Comment: [`wrap_stream`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.9/hyper/body/struct.Body.html#method.wrap_stream) requires that the stream data meet the `'static` bound. Yours does not.

Comment: See also [How do I stream a hyper Request's Body from a slow-processing side thread that produces chunks of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56435409/155423)

Comment: But the 'static bound means, that this data is always held in memory or? As data can get very large and there will be a lot of requests on different ressources I think won't be a good idea. As far as I understood the docs, I think 'static bound should be avoided if possible or?

Comment: Also I've added an async context, but the lifetime problem still exists. Also, If I remove the lifetime specifiers ('a) then compiler advice is to use them. Please have a look. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=587b4d12786a94801ffd1a42ca71f2a4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the `'a` itself, but in the fact that the [`std::slice::chunks()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks) function returns an iterator that borrows the original slice. You are trying to create a stream future from this `Chunks<'_, u8>` value, but the stream requires it to be `'static`. Even if your `Resource` did not have the `'a` lifetime, you would still have the `r.data` borrowed, and it would still fail.

Remember that here `'static` does not mean that the value lives forever, but that it can be made to live as long as necessary. That is, the future must not hold any (non-`'static`) borrows.

You could clone all the data, but if it is very big, it can be costly. If so, you could try using `Bytes`, that is just like `Vec<u8>` but reference counted.

It looks like there is no `Bytes::chunks()` function that returns an iterator of `Bytes`. Fortunately it is easy to do it by hand.

Lastly, remember that iterators in Rust are lazy, so they keep the original data borrowed, even if it is a `Bytes`. So we need to collect them into a `Vec` to actually own the data ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=75be0ebc035eb490e20349fe2622f19f)):

```rust
pub struct Resource {
    pub data: Bytes,
}

impl<'a> Response<'a> {
    pub fn build(&mut self) -> Result<hyper::Response<hyper::Body>, hyper::http::Error> {
        let mut response = hyper::Response::builder();
        match self.resource {
            Some(r) => {
                let len = r.data.len();
                let chunks = (0..len)
                    .step_by(100)
                    .map(|x| {
                        let range = x..len.min(x + 100);
                        Ok(r.data.slice(range))
                    })
                    .collect::<Vec<Result<Bytes, std::convert::Infallible>>>();
                response.body(hyper::Body::wrap_stream(stream::iter(chunks)))
            }
            None => response.body(hyper::Body::from("")),
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: We can avoid the call to `collect()` if we notice that `stream::iter()` takes ownership of an `IntoIterator` that can be evaluated lazily, as long as we make it `'static`. It can be done if we do a (cheap) clone of `r.data` and move it into the lambda ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f745a0327229e626c107171661ce43d8)):

```rust
    let data = r.data.clone();
    let len = data.len();
    let chunks = (0..len).step_by(100)
        .map(move |x| {
            let range = x .. len.min(x + 100);
            Result::<_, std::convert::Infallible>::Ok(data.slice(range))
                    });
    response.body(hyper::Body::wrap_stream(stream::iter(chunks)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. This has expanded my understanding of Rust by quite a bit. It works great.